# Gluon Mobile: Change project from Free tier to Indie tier

Tags: licensing, gluon, gluon-mobile

I'm confused about the licensing options. Can anyone explain to me whether I can start developing my project with the *Free* tier and later change to an *Indie* tier? The reason I'm asking is because the possibility of changing tier wouldn't make sense from a business point of view, since that would mean that developers could simply develop their app under the *Free* tier until the end of the project and switch to the *Indie* tier right before compilation and distribution and cancel the *Indie* subscription after a month.

So this must mean that I have to start developing with the *Indie* tier from the very beginning of the project if I don't want a nag screen, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the documentation

> the free tier is available and fully functional for you to test with before parting with any money.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch anytime by adding the valid license to your project. Applications compiled and distributed with valid license will work without showing the nag screen